# DevExpress Reactive Get all filters when you use custom filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

I want get all filters for the GridExport but when i use onFiltersChange my filter is deselect, but when I delete onFiltersChange it's work properly.

I use hook useState for setFilters ans filters.

I use this version in my package.json:

"@devexpress/dx-react-chart": "^2.6.4",
"react": "^16.13.1",

How can I do this ?

This is my grid:

```
<Grid
  rows={items}
  columns={columns}>
   <StockQuantityTypeProvider for={["stockQuantity"]}/>
   <DateTypeProvider for={["lastCountingPeriodUpdate"]}/>

   <SearchState/>
   <SortingState sorting={sorting} onSortingChange={setSorting}/>
   <FilteringState filters={filters} onFiltersChange={setFilters}/>
   <PagingState defaultPageSize={20}/>
   <SelectionState selection={itemsSelectedIndex} onSelectionChange={onChangeSelection}/>

   <IntegratedSorting/>
   <IntegratedFiltering/>
   <IntegratedPaging/>
   <IntegratedSelection/>

    <Table
      messages={{noData: "Aucun article"}}
      rowComponent={tableRow}
    />
    {currentUser?.authorization?.hasWriteRights && <TableSelection showSelectAll/>}

    <Toolbar/>
    <SearchPanel messages={{searchPlaceholder: "Rechercher..."}}/>

    <CustomToolbarMarkup onClickRefresh={onClickRefresh}>
      <CustomToolbarButton/>
    </CustomToolbarMarkup>

    <TableColumnResizing/>
    <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls/>
    <TableFilterRow
      showFilterSelector
      cellComponent={(props) => 
        <CustomFilterCell {...props} rows={items} columns={[
          {columnName: "baseUnitOfMeasure", type: "selection"},
          {columnName: "lastCountingPeriodUpdate", type: "dateRange"},
        ]}/>
      }
    />
    <PagingPanel pageSizes={[20, 40, 60]}/>
    <ExportPanel startExport={startExport}/>
</Grid>

<GridExporter
  ref={exporterRef}
  columns={columns}
  rows={items}
  sorting={sorting}
  filters={filters}
  selection={itemsSelectedIndex}
  onSave={onSave}
/>
```

And this is my custom filter:

```
const SelectionFilterCell = ({filter, onFilter, rows, property}) => {
  const saveUnitOfMeasure = Array.from(new Set(rows.map((row) => row[property])));

  return (
    <th style={{fontWeight: "normal"}}>
      <Input
        type={"select"}
        className="form-control stock-propertyTab-inputSelect"
        value={filter ? filter.value : ""}
        onChange={(e) => onFilter(e.target.value ? {value: e.target.value, operation: "equal"} : null)}>
        <option key={-1} value="">
          Filtrer...
        </option>
        {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          saveUnitOfMeasure.map((unit, index) => {
            if (unit !== null && unit !== "") {
              return (
                <option key={index} value={unit}>
                  {unit}
                </option>
              );
            }
          })
        }
      </Input>
    </th>
  );
};

export const CustomFilterCell = (props) => {
  const {column,rows,columns}=props;
  let isCustom = false;
  let propertyUse = undefined;

  columns.forEach((c) => {
    if (!isCustom) {
      if (column.name === c.columnName) {
        isCustom = true;
        propertyUse = c;
      }
    }
  });

  if (isCustom && propertyUse !== undefined) {
    if (propertyUse.type === "selection") {
      return <SelectionFilterCell {...props} content={rows} property={propertyUse.columnName} />;
    }
  }
  return <TableFilterRow.Cell {...props} />;
};
```